# Adding a row in between of a gridview in asp.net deletes the last row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am facing an issue in a gridview in ASP.NET when I dynamically add a new row to a pre-populated GridView

My Grid View consists of element of two types ( say A and B) which are pre-populated from the database

The code I have written first calculates the count of elements of Type A , then adds a new row  as a "ROW Seperator" , between the elements of Row A and Row B.
I write this bit of logic in the row data bound event of the grid view

My grid view consists of checkboxes for both elements of type A and Type B.

Now if I check the **last element** in the grid View , I realizied after putting a break point that the given element no longer exists in the gridView although it visually appears in the front end for the user to **"check"**.

I belive this is something to do with the dynamic row separator I added to the gridView but I can't seem to understand why.

Below is my code.

```
    //Page Load
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Getting count of elements of type A and storing it in a global variable
        globalA_count= GetCount(dataset);
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
    // GRIDVIEW DATABOUND

    protected void gvAccessories_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //DATA SET IS ALREADY SORTED SO THAT "A" ELEMNTS AND 'B" ELEMENTS ARE GROUPED TOGETHERE
    if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "B")
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(236, 236, 236);
    }
    /*** "localA_Count" is used as a counter to count "A" elements within   rowdatabound
       * globalA_count" holds the count of "A" elements already calculated
       *  when "localA_Count" equals "globalA_count",it means all 
        A type elements are already traversed**/
     else if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "A")
     {
         localA_Count++;
         if (localA_Count== globalA_count)
         {
             // ADD ROW SEPERATOR
             GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);   
             row.CssClass = "StdGridHeader";
             TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
             cell1.Text = "sample text"
             cell1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
             cell1.ColumnSpan = 4;
             row.Cells.Add(cell1);
             ((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(globalA_count+ 1, row);
          }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you missed some of the code part as there are some condition which places without any method which is not possible. @Ananth

Comment: There is a function called GetCount where I determine the total count of elements of Type "A" , I've only left that. But I am not sure if that will help .

Comment: @NayanKatkani  Edited the code .I enclosed the previous code in the rowdatabound function .

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the code, can u clarify what is happening with some more details?

Comment: @JuniorJohn Visually everything works fine. But on a post back on hitting the "Continue" button , the gridview count is messed up. Before adding the " Seperator" the count of rows is 48 . But after adding the seperator the count should be 49 instead it still shows 48 and the "nth row" or the last row is deleted .( when viewing the details on breakpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding code to correct event? Your gridview id is "gridview" but event is different gvAccessories_RowDataBound() ?

Comment: Actually I edited the nomenclature of the code before pasting it here "gridview " is equivalent to "gvAccessories"